# Bounded linear functional as difference of measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set and $A=C(X,\mathbb{R})$ the vector space of continuous functions on $X$ equipped with the supremum norm. If $\mu$ is Radon measure on $X$, then the linear functional $L_\mu:A\to\mathbb{R},\, f\mapsto\int fd\mu$ is a bounded operator. Clearly, not every bounded linear functional $A\to\mathbb{R}$ can be represented like this: Just take $-L_\mu$ for instance. But is it true that every bounded linear functional $A\to\mathbb{R}$ is the difference $L_\mu-L_\lambda$ for Radon measures $\mu,\lambda$ on $X$?

Comment: Use Hahn decomposition: Any real measure is a difference of two positive measures.

Comment: You can find this in detail in most common real analysis books. For an example, see Royden's *Real Analysis*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's true. That is the statement (in the compact case) of the [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem):

> **Theorem** (Riesz-Markov-Kakutani). Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Then every bounded linear functional on $C_c(X)$ (the space of compactly supported continuous functions, if $X$ is compact, this equals $C(X)$) $f\in C_c(X)'$ can be represented by a unique Radon measure, that is:
> $$ \forall y \in C_c(X): f(y) = \int_X y\, d\mu. $$

Note, that one considers signed Radon measures $\mu \colon \mathrm{Bor}(X) \to [-\infty, \infty]$ here. As you state, each of these can be written as the difference of two "classic" (i. e. positive) Radon measures. That is the statement of the [Hahn-Jordan decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem).